# Using IF in google spreadsheet cell returns #ERROR

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am starting to use google spreadsheet to manage some dates for personal convenience and this formula for a cell returns me `#ERRROR!`

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1), "Unknown datetime", C1 + 3/24)
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

I'm probably not setting things at the right place, here is a basic sample :
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you give example of the value in `C1` that is causing formula to error?

Comment: Something like `22/03/2016 16:06:00`

Comment: Does it really `#ERRROR` instead of `#ERROR` ?

Comment: Just edited the question with a screenshot to make what I did more clear.

Comment: The top right corner shows a red triangle, pass your mouse pointer over that triangle and check out the error message.

Comment: What is your locale? Have you tried using semicolon instead of comma?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add 8 hours to A1, then add it as Time.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1), "Unknown datetime", A1 +time(8, 0, 0))
```

[image: googlesheets_add_time]

Comment: Still the same thing, error on formula analysis/parsing. No clue where it can come from

Comment: Is A1 a true datetime? Does it correct itself if you use =Now() in A1? What language are you working under?

Comment: A1 is just a string I enter, however, setting `=now()` as A1 value doesn't change anything. I'm not working with any language, thre is no VBA or anything, it's just for an utility spreadsheet for myself

Comment: Well, there usually isn't any VBA in a google-sheet but that is beside the point. As you can see from my supplied image, this works with google-sheets; suggest you try it on a new en-us sheet. Sorry to say, but if I cannot replicate the problem, it is unlikely that I will be able to offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure A1 is formatted to time - Format > Number > Time.
2. If you change the date to 03/03/2016 11:54:15, does it work? If yes, the expected date format is date/month/year while you have month/date/year in the cell.